# Name of this type of exponential notation?

Tags: notation

If I have the number $45682$ and I write it as $$4\times 10^4+ 5\times 10^3+ 6\times 10^2+8\times 10^1 +2\times 10^0,$$ what is the latter notation called?

Comment: Wikipedia calls the fractional part (and unit part for some reason) of this notation the [decimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation) of the number.

Comment: I learned it as expanded notation, but I don't think there's any significant difference between the two, other than generality?

Comment: I would call that a decimal expansion (which is commonly shortened as $45682$)

Answer (score 1):

It's called [expanded notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_of_the_numeral_system). Also, that last term should be $2\cdot10^0$.